# Why is styled-components adding my attributes to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, styled-components

I have this in some parts of the code:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

type PropsType = {
  direction?: 'horizontal' | 'vertical'
  flex?: number | string
  width?: number | string
  minWidth?: number | string
  height?: number | string
  minHeight?: number | string
  fill?: string
  padding?: number | string
  paddingTop?: string | number
  paddingRight?: string | number
  paddingBottom?: string | number
  paddingLeft?: string | number
}

const Box = styled.div<PropsType>`
  display: flex;
  ${({ padding }) =>
    padding &&
    `padding: ${typeof padding === 'number' ? `${padding}px` : padding};`}
  ${({ width }) =>
    width && `width: ${typeof width === 'number' ? `${width}px` : width};`}
  ${({ minWidth }) =>
    minWidth &&
    `min-width: ${typeof minWidth === 'number' ? `${minWidth}px` : minWidth};`}
  ${({ height }) =>
    height && `height: ${typeof height === 'number' ? `${height}px` : height};`}
  ${({ minHeight }) =>
    minHeight &&
    `min-height: ${
      typeof minHeight === 'number' ? `${minHeight}px` : minHeight
    };`}
  ${({ flex }) => flex && `flex: ${flex};`}
  ${({ fill }) => fill && `background-color: ${fill};`}
  ${({ direction }) =>
    direction &&
    `flex-direction: ${direction === 'horizontal' ? 'row' : 'column'};`}
  ${({ paddingTop }) =>
    paddingTop &&
    `padding-top: ${
      typeof paddingTop === 'number' ? `${paddingTop}px` : paddingTop
    };`}
  ${({ paddingRight }) =>
    paddingRight &&
    `padding-right: ${
      typeof paddingRight === 'number' ? `${paddingRight}px` : paddingRight
    };`}
  ${({ paddingBottom }) =>
    paddingBottom &&
    `padding-bottom: ${
      typeof paddingBottom === 'number' ? `${paddingBottom}px` : paddingBottom
    };`}
  ${({ paddingLeft }) =>
    paddingLeft &&
    `padding-left: ${
      typeof paddingLeft === 'number' ? `${paddingLeft}px` : paddingLeft
    };`}
`

export default Box
```

And then I have this:

```
export default function Page() {

  return (
    <>
      <Box padding={24} width="100%">
        <h1>(tab)</h1>
      </Box>
      <Box fill={COLOR.white} paddingTop={24} paddingBottom={24}>
        (Text)
      </Box>
      <Box padding={24}>
        (Output)
      </Box>
    </>
  )
}
```

The relevant part is the `fill` attribute, and other attributes, which show up in the DOM:

[image]

Is this normal behavior? Or how do I remove it from the DOM?

I am using Next.js and have the default `next.config.js`, with this `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "index.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed we normally expect that `styled-components` is [smart enough](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props) to *not pass* extra props to styled base HTML tags (like `div` in this case):

> If the styled target is a simple element (e.g. `styled.div`), [...] styled-components [is] smart enough to filter non-standard attributes automatically for you.

Unfortunately, the "smart enough" is *not enough* in this case: `fill` attribute is [standard for SVG elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill), hence `styled-components` lets it through...

---

A very simple workaround is to use a [transient prop](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props) instead. It consists in prefixing the prop with a dollar sign:

> If you want to prevent props meant to be consumed by styled components from being passed to the underlying React node or rendered to the DOM element, you can prefix the prop name with a dollar sign (`$`), turning it into a transient prop.

```
const Box2 = styled.div<{ $fill?: string; }>`
  ${({ $fill }) => $fill && `background-color: ${$fill};`}
`;

<Box2 $fill="yellow">Content...</Box2>
```

Unfortunately, this means slightly changing your internal API.

---

Another workaround consists in using the [`shouldForwardProp`](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#shouldforwardprop) configuration. With this, we can precisely specify what should be passed through or not:

> A prop that fails the test isn't passed down to underlying components, just like a transient prop.

```
const Box3 = styled.div.withConfig({
  shouldForwardProp(prop, isValidProp) {
    return (prop as string) !== "fill" && isValidProp(prop);
  }
})<{ fill?: string; }>`
  ${({ fill }) => fill && `background-color: ${fill};`}
`;

<Box3 fill="yellow">Content...</Box3>
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-silence-mp54zv?file=/src/App.tsx

---

Some more explanation on the `styled-components` built-in "smart" filter: as implied above, as soon as the prop is a standard attribute for *any* HTML standard element (like `fill` for SVG in this case), it is white listed, and passed through.

This is because `styled-components` actually relies on [`@emotion/is-prop-valid`](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/tree/v10.0.6/packages/is-prop-valid), which implements the filter as a single common white list for simplicity, instead of having a list per HTML standard tag.

We can find the `fill` attribute white listed [here](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/blob/v10.0.6/packages/is-prop-valid/src/props.js#L276).